# VBA: xmlhttp response paste is sometimes omitting tabs?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT2: I can't find why it might be pasting it incorrectly but the responseText reads as tab every time and I can just split it into an array and avoid the clipboard altogether. I'd still appreciate if someone has any ideas as to why this might've happened.

```
  Sub example()

  Dim clip As Object, D As Object, H As Object, URL As String

  Set clip = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
  Set H = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
  Set D = CreateObject("HTMLFile")

'authentication
'xmlrequest
'here

    URL = "https:/someinternal.site/tsv?filter=querystring"

  H.Open "GET", URL
  H.send

  clip.SetText H.responseText
  clip.PutInClipboard
  Sheet1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
  End Sub
```

I'm trying to query an internal site that responds with a .TSV and I'm getting inconsistent results. Sometimes it pastes in properly split into columns, other times it ommits all of the deliminators and drops it in like this:

```
FullNameFirstLast
John SmithJohnSmith
```

When it should be:

```
FullName    First    Last
John Smith    John    Smith
```

I've found resources where people talk about using the TextToColumns manually to set the default for the deliminator, but when I paste into Excel, it looks the same - all tabs are taken out. If I paste the website (just a raw .TSV) into notepad++ and from there into Excel, it properly shows the tabs and line breaks on the editor and works in Excel. If I debug.Print H.responseText, the response it gives me replaces all of the tabs with 4 spaces which I guess is pretty normal for the immediate window but it doesn't help me.

Elsewhere in the code, I also query a .CSV file using the same method which I think is breaking it. Are there any parameters I can set to properly parse the response, or another method to use? For this I could use a querytable connection, but due to the authentication that needs to happen first, this has its own problems and I try to avoid them like the plague.

EDIT: paste dump from Excel pasted as an image instead of text. Even more confusing is when I copy and paste the Excel output into notepad or notepad++, it properly displays the tabs. Pasting it back into Excel produces the same result. This means the response is coming out right, but Excel itself is doing something strange with the tabs... Manual TextToColumns worked when it wasn't finding the deliminator earlier. **Sometimes it comes out as four spaces and other times, invisible tabs - this is the issue.**

[image: output]

Comment: Can you provide an example of a failing response (that fails when you expect it to split)

Comment: Added that, and found out that the problem is coming from the tabs being interpreted as four spaces or as a (hidden) tab.